# software centre error on ubuntu

Tags: software-center, 17.04

So i am new to Ubuntu and I am currently using Ubuntu 17.04.
I tried updating software through the "software updater". After this I had trouble with the software center when I clicked on its icon it just showed the loading graphics where the mouse is placed .the Application doesn't open.
so I tried reinstalling software center.[this is the error I got after trying to install software center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a4pJ.png)

[edit 1] i understood that there is no package called software-centre.
i installed gnome-software but my main issue still persists.

Comment: There is no package called `software-center` in ubuntu.

Comment: The package is `gnome-software`

Comment: did that but still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I *personally* wouldn't worry about the software centre. I never use either of them (Ubuntu Software/Ubuntu Software Centre). I always look up what kind of program I'm wanting to install, search how to install it, then follow the instructions. With some software, you have to add a PPA, install, say, `snap` or something, and all of this would be listed in the installation instructions. I just find that there is *typically* better software available from sources other than the software centre. However, if you're just trying to update your software, you can run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you got:

```
E: package 'software-center' has no installation candidate
```

means exactly what it says. There is no Ubuntu Software Center package in the default 17.04 repositories. Instead 17.04 uses Ubuntu Software (*gnome-software*) as the default GUI software management application.

Close the Ubuntu Software window if it is open. Open the terminal and type:

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Comment: i installed gnome-software package. still i am unable to open the software app.

Comment: No doesn't open.